# Disable a KeyTyped event based on its type

Tags: java, keyboard-events, keylistener

When I press any key I receive 3 events: KeyPressed, KeyTyped and KeyReleased. For KeyPressed and KeyReleased it knows where the key came from e.g. the KeyPad. However, for the KeyTyped event it seems to lose all knowledge that it came from the keypad. Any idea why that is?

This is some of the toString when i press the 4 key in the keypad:

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='4',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN
```

I can consume the KeyPressed and KeyReleased if it comes from the keypad but I need to do the same for KeyTyped:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD){
        keyEvent.consume();
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

So my question is how do I stop it from issuing the KeyTyped event if it comes from the keypad?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> the location of the key that was pressed or released. Always returns KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN for KEY_TYPED events.

The reason is that `KEY_TYPED` events are kind of *logical* events, they just tell you that a key has been typed ignoring low-level details of how it has been typed. Ex: in a text editor, you just don't need to know how a key has been typed or a character generated. It is generally considered as a very bad idea to try to know it for such application.

`KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` are much more *physical* events. Ex: in a game you may want to do different things when release or press are generated : press>>>start running, release>>>>stop running. So, it may be interesting to know which physical key has been used, because you are more interested in the details of the events and the keyboard layout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I sort of understand that but it still doesnt really explain how i can disable the keypad. If the user has the num lock key enabled then the KEY_TYPED doesnt get issued. Is there a way of fooling the application into thinking the NumLock is always enabled?? or by saying if KeyPressed is from the keypad then ignore the 'KeyTyped' that is to follow.

Comment: You may success doing such a trick but it is mostly unholy. `KEY_TYPED` is used to represents chars, not keys, so there is no difference how the char was generated. It may be strange that you want non keypad chars but not keypad ones... Why don't you consume every `TYPED` chars ? Or why don't you catch `KeyEvent`s on your component ? Your context is not clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It looks like I have sort of fixed this (although it is abit of a hack!). For anyone interested I basically look at the KEY_PRESSED event received in the dispatchKeyEvent() and set a boolean if it is from the keypad. The next event that is received (i.e. the KEY_TYPED or the KEY_RELEASED) consumes the event and returns true meaning that nothing gets sent to the textbox. That is the only way i could find around this problem :)